# Wordpress Media Uploader : How to add custom button on featured image tab

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, media-library, media-modal, backbone

We are working on the plugin and try to add a custom button near 'set featured image' but we can not able to find out any solution or clue how to add it using media library function.

Can someone please help me on this?

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: what will do this button ?

Comment: If user click on this button. We will optimize the selected image and add an optimized image to the post. This include in our client requirement feature list.